# Java 8 JSON optimisation

Tags: java, json, java-stream, collectors

I have a JSON with a list of students as below - for each Student, I want to print the hobbies, if no hobby is present show NA using Java 8. I have written the below code which is working but I am having to use 2 maps. Please suggest if this code can be optimized.

JSON

```json
{
    "students":[
        {
            "fullName":"AAAAA",
            "standard":10,
            "hobbies":[
                "programming",
                "reading"
            ]
        },
        {
        }
    ]
}
```

JAVA 8

```java
Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap = reportCard.getStudents().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getFullName));
Map<String, String> studentMap2 = new TreeMap<>();
studentMap.keySet().forEach(key -> Optional.ofNullable(studentMap.get(key).get(0).getHobbies())
                        .ifPresentOrElse(hobbies -> studentMap2.put(key, hobbies.stream().map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.joining(";"))), () -> studentMap2.put(key, "NA")));
```

Comment: Questions about roptimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Java 8**

You can use the `collectors.toMap` from **java 8** to have the desired output as shown in the code below:

*Here,*

1. I have taken the sample json in the **Text Block(feature from jdk15)** to have the json in a readable format.*(You can have it in the simple string format also)*
2. I have used `collectors.toMap` in which we will have the key as student Name and for the value i have checked if the hobbies list is not null and should not be empty and then perform the downstream operation of joining all the hobbies of the student otherwise it will have "NA" and i have used **merger** `(a,b) -> a + "," + b`, it will combine the hobbies of same student with same name if exists and `TreeMap::new` will sort the hobbies in natural order.

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String input = """
                {
                     "students": [
                         {
                             "fullName": "AAAAA",
                             "standard": 10,
                             "hobbies": [
                                         "programming",
                                         "reading"
                                        ]
                         },
                         {
                             "fullName": "BBBB",
                             "standard": 12,
                             "hobbies": [
                                         "music",
                                         "reading"
                                        ]
                         },
                         {
                             "fullName": "CCCC",
                             "standard": 12,
                             "hobbies": [
                                        ]
                         },
                         {
                 
                         }
                     ]
                 }
                 
                """;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        StudentData data = mapper.readValue(input,StudentData.class);
        

        Map<String,String> output =
            data.getStudentList().stream().filter(a -> a.getName()!=null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName,
                            x -> (x.getHobbies()!=null && !x.getHobbies().isEmpty() ? String.join(",",x.getHobbies()) : "NA")
    ,(a,b) -> a + "," + b,TreeMap::new));
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output::**

```
{AAAAA=programming,reading, BBBB=music,reading, CCCC=NA}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split getting data and pring it.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Root root = new Root();
    Map<String, Set<String>> studentHobbies = getStudentHobbies(root);
    printStudentHobbies(studentHobbies);
}

private static Map<String, Set<String>> getStudentHobbies(Root root) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(root.getStudents()).orElse(List.of()).stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getFullName,
                                             student -> Optional.ofNullable(student.getHobbies())
                                                                .orElse(Set.of())));
}

private static void printStudentHobbies(Map<String, Set<String>> studentHobbies) {
    studentHobbies.forEach((fullName, hobbies) ->
                                   System.out.format("%s - %s\n",
                                                     fullName,
                                                     hobbies.isEmpty() ? "NA" : hobbies));
}
```

---

Just in case, we have following classes

```java
private static class Root {

    private List<Student> students;

}

private static class Student {

    private String fullName;
    private int standard;
    private Set<String> hobbies;
}
```